# What am I doing wrong? Trying to retrieve data from SQLite within a AsyncTask, but it crashes

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-room

I am currently playing around with Android - Room Persistence Library, and trying to retrieve non-live data from the SQLite database, which then needs to be handled and checked against data from Firestore Cloud. All this is run within a AsyncTask but when I am trying to retrieve the data from Room, I get the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.

I understand that I cannot call a database method from the main thread, but all this is called from the AsyncTask which should handle all what I stated above. What am I doing wrong?

I have tried to create a asyncTask within my MainRepository which in short terms looks like this:

```
public List<Shift> getAllShiftsForJobExport(int jobId){
        try {
            return new GetShiftsForJobAsync(shiftDao).execute(jobId).get();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

This didn't work all the time and ended up giving some weird results...

My AsyncTask where I am trying to retrieve data from Room and compare to Firestore cloud looks like this:

```
private static class DownloadDataFromCloud extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private CloudViewModel viewModel;
        private FirebaseFirestore db;
        private String userId;

        DownloadDataFromCloud(FragmentActivity activity){
            viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(activity).get(CloudViewModel.class);
        }

        private void downloadData(){
            List<Job> jobs = viewModel.getAllJobs();
            Map<String, Job> jobDocuments = new HashMap<>();
            for(Job job : jobs){
                if(job.getDocumentId() != null){
                    jobDocuments.put(job.getDocumentId(), job);
                }
            }
            CollectionReference jobsCollection = db.collection("jobs");
            jobsCollection.whereEqualTo("userId", userId)
                    .get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                    for(QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots){
                        Job job = new Job();
                        job.convertCloudToObject(documentSnapshot);

                        if(jobDocuments.containsKey(job.getDocumentId())){
                            job.setId(jobDocuments.get(job.getDocumentId()).getId());
                            viewModel.updateJob(job);
                            downloadShiftData(job.getId(), job.getDocumentId());
                        }else {
                            viewModel.insertJobWithReturn(job, new AsyncResponse<Long>() {
                                @Override
                                public void processFinish(Long output) {
                                    long jobId = output;
                                    downloadShiftData((int) jobId, job.getDocumentId());
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        private void downloadShiftData(int jobId, String documentId){
            List<Shift> shifts = viewModel.getAllShiftForJob(jobId);
            Map<String, Shift> shiftDocuments = new HashMap<>();
            for(Shift shift : shifts){
                if(shift.getDocumentId() != null){
                    shiftDocuments.put(shift.getDocumentId(), shift);
                }
            }
            CollectionReference shiftCollection = db.collection("shifts");
            shiftCollection.whereEqualTo("userId", userId)
                    .whereEqualTo("jobDocumentId", documentId)
                    .get().addOnSuccessListener(queryDocumentSnapshots -> {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                            Shift shift = new Shift();
                            shift.convertCloudToObject(documentSnapshot);
                            if(shiftDocuments.containsKey(shift.getDocumentId())){
                                shift.setId(shiftDocuments.get(shift.getDocumentId()).getId());
                                viewModel.updateShift(shift);
                            }else {
                                shift.setJobId(jobId);
                                viewModel.insertShift(shift);
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            downloadData();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
            userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid();
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            super.onCancelled();
        }
    }
```

The complete stacktrace i get is:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.
        at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.assertNotMainThread(RoomDatabase.java:228)
        at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.query(RoomDatabase.java:255)
        at androidx.room.util.DBUtil.query(DBUtil.java:54)
        at com.*.daos.ShiftDao_Impl.getAllShiftsForJobExport(ShiftDao_Impl.java:909)
        at com.*.MainRepository.getAllShiftsForJobExport(MainRepository.java:203)
        at com.*.CloudViewModel.getAllShiftForJob(CloudViewModel.java:33)
        at com.*.CloudHandler$DownloadDataFromCloud.downloadShiftData(CloudHandler.java:216)
        at com.*.CloudHandler$DownloadDataFromCloud.access$300(CloudHandler.java:171)
        at com.*.CloudHandler$DownloadDataFromCloud$1.onSuccess(CloudHandler.java:200)
        at com.*.CloudHandler$DownloadDataFromCloud$1.onSuccess(CloudHandler.java:190)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzn.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Edit - Code for GetShiftsForJobAsync:

```
private static class GetShiftsForJobAsync extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, List<Shift>>{

        private ShiftDao shiftDao;

        GetShiftsForJobAsync(ShiftDao shiftDao){
            this.shiftDao = shiftDao;
        }

        @Override
        protected List<Shift> doInBackground(Integer... integers) {
            return shiftDao.getAllShiftsForJobExport(integers[0]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: add your code where you're trying to fetch data. Your error clearly states you're doing operations on main thread

Comment: @VedprakashWagh I accedently posted to quickly, it is all updated now.

Comment: By the way, you don't need to add AsyncTask for fetching data from Firebase. You can directly run the code for fetching data from Firebase database on your UI thread. It does all the work internally

Comment: @VedprakashWagh The reason for me running it in a AsyncTask is becuase i am also accessing the Database, but it still gives me the error, which i do not understand...

Comment: where is the code for `GetShiftsForJobAsync`?

Comment: @ItamarKerbel i added it now in my edit :)

Comment: When using get() on an AsyncTask you're executing it synchronously. That will generate work on the main thread that should be executed on other thread. Try removing the get() from the call function.

Answer (score 0):

When using `get()` on an `AsyncTask` you're executing it **synchronously**. That will generate work on the main thread that should be executed on other thread. Try removing the `get()` from the call function.

As per the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get()):

> Waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result.

Comment: I have already read this material, but does it still do the work on the main thread even though it is called from a AsyncTask? Which is what I am doing in my case. I start a method from a AsyncTask, since I want to handle network operations, and within that AsyncTask I need the List<Shift> from the database inorder to probably upload / download the data from the cloud. I have also tried to run the database method without the AsyncTask that I added in my edit, but even though it runs in a background thread I still get the error message

Comment: The problem it´s not the code inside the AsyncTask, it´s the AsyncTask call itself. Since it has a get() it will be executed on the same calling thread (I supose, the main UI thread as it breaks). Try removing the get(), so the call gets executed on it´s own separated thread. You can still handle the UI Thread on the postExecute() method.

Comment: I will try it out once I am home again, but just to clarify. Even though I use the get() method on my GetShiftsForJobAsync class, which is called from my DownloadDataFromCloud class then the get() is still executed on the Main Thread? I might have the completely wrong mindset on how AsyncTask works...

Comment: Might be that the onSuccess Firestore callback is the Main UI thread. To make a quick test, you can use Anko´s doAsync{} to execute that block on another thread.

Comment: Ohh, never thought of that, I will take a look at it later and let you know what I figure out!